# Beit ha-Otzar (Shadal)

Tags: jewish-books

I'm tearing my hair out trying to find an online copy of Shadal's Beit ha-Otzar volume 2. Volume 1 seems fairly widely available online but not volume 2... Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are. He also published a third volume.

https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=cCg_AQAAIAAJ&hl=en_US&pg=GBS.PR1

Comment: Sadly that's just a listing, there's no actual ebook available there.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I can see the whole book there. Some countries block access.

Comment: Or try this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eVtubXaWeeYuytkBmC0sMvaM5CbT8Frx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ah that must be it. I’m in the UK and had no access. Thank you!!

Comment: Indeed, my friends from the EU have the same problem. VPN can help.